# SonarQube implies var is not null

Tags: java, android-studio, sonarqube

In this example below, SonarQube complains that `model.toString()` is `not null` and (`model == null`) is always `false`, need some help to understand what can be done to fix it. because the bookmark is initialized as a variable within the if statement and apparently will be `null`.

```
public static class Mapper implements DataStore.ModelMapper<Membership, 
MembershipPassDTO> {            
    @Override
    public MembershipPassDTO mapModel(Membership model) {
        VALogger.e("SULOD Membership Mapper", "" + model.toString());

        if (model == null) {
            return new MembershipPassDTO(model, "", "", "", "", "", "");
        }
        return new MembershipPassDTO(model, model.getVitalityMembershipId(), model.getMembershipNumber(), model.getCustomerNumber(),
                model.getVitalityStatus(), model.getMembershipStartDate(), model.getMembershipStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: [Java !== JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Answer (score 2):

whenever you call `model.toString()` and **your model is null indeed**, then your method will throw a `NullPoiunterException`.

but if `model.toString()` did not throw a `NullPointerEcxeption` then it's obvious, that `model == null` is **always** false...

well - that's what SonarQube is trying to tell you...

---

if you want to get rid of the warning you can do what [jensgram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52162/jensgram) suggested:

`VALogger.e("SULOD Membership Mapper", ""+model); //implicitly calls toString()`

Comment: This. Also, the `"" + model.toString()` construct is redundant at best; either explicitly cast to `String` (`model.toString()`, NPE prone) or do so implicitly (`"" + model`, NPE safe.)

Comment: @jensgram thank you very much - join https://codereview.stackexchange.com and help us to create better software =)

Comment: @jensgram I tried using String (model.toString(), NPE prone) and ("" + model, NPE safe.) but I'm only getting red lines at rone and safe words.

Comment: @JoanaMa.LupeGuarin Oh, what I meant was that you should use _either_ `VALogger.e("SULOD Membership Mapper", model.toString());` _or_ `VALogger.e("SULOD Membership Mapper", "" + model);`. Both will ensure that the second parameter is of type `String`.